# Search does not reply with the filtered result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, pg-search

All,

please help me with a simple feature...I can´t determine the error.
So this is my simple user story

**Expected:** As a user I want to get a list of results based on my search-criteria (e.g. title, description)

**Actual:** What I get :-( always the full list of pins, instead of the filtered one.

For this, I use the gems pg_search and my view is written in HAML

application.html.haml including the search-bar:

```
.container
  = form_tag pins_path, method: :get, class: "search", role: "search" do
    .container
  = form_tag pins_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" do
    %p
      = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control"
      = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default"
```

pins_controller:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @pins = Pin.search_for(params[:query])
  else
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end   
end
```

And finally index.html.haml:

```
- @pins.each do |pin|
  .box.panel.panel-default
    = link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), pin
    .panel-body
      %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
      %p.user
      Submitted by
      = pin.user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `search` params, whicle in controller you are expecting `query` param and so checking if `params[:query]` present or not

So replace `params[:query]` with `params[:search]` in your controller or change your input filed name to `query` in your search form.